# Bootstrap Table not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, twitter-bootstrap-2

My table that I am developing for my landing page works fine on other browsers but doesn't work for Internet Explorer.

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.0 as a framework and fancybox for the image gallery below. The table doesn't appear at all in Internet Explorer.

Bear in mind that there is normally 3 different tables on the same page to deal with different screen resolutions, I am using media queries to manage which table should remain visible. Please help me out guys to find a way to make the tables work properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset ="UTF-8">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!--Custom CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet"href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/CSS/Landingpage.css"/>
      <!-- Add jQuery library -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Add fancyBox -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css"media="screen" />
      <!--fancybox javascript-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="Title">
               <p>Title</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3" class="col-md-3">  </div>
            <div id="TextBox" class="col-lg-6" class="col-md-6" >
               <p> text box   </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3" class="col-md-3">  </div>
         </div>
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
               <style media="screen and (min-width:0px)">
                  #Large_table {display:none;}
                  #Medium_table {display:none;}
               </style>
               <style media="screen and (min-width:992px)"> 
                  #Small_table {display:none;}
                  #Large_table {display:none;} 
                  #Medium_table {display:initial;}    
               </style>
               <style media="screen and (min-width:1200px)">
                  #Small_table {display:none;}
                  #Medium_table {display:none;}
                  #Large_table {display:initial;}
                  td { width:311px;
                  height:228px;
                  }
               </style>
               <div class="table-responsive">
                  <!--Small table -->
                  <table class="table" id="Small_table">
                     <thead>  </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td> 
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Babble City-Crimson.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Babble City-Crimson.jpg" />
                              </a>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Club.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Club.jpg" alt="" />
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Scribble.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"> 
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Scribble.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Gem-Main Bar.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Gem-Main Bar.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> 
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Grace-Milk Bar.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Grace-Milk Bar.jpg" />
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Kanaloa-Club.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Kanaloa-Club.jpg"/>
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Clinic.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"> 
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Clinic.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Fruitbox Bar.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Fruitbox Bar.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!-- Medium table --->
                  <table class="table" id="Medium_table">
                     <thead>  </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td> 
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Babble City-Crimson.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Babble City-Crimson.jpg" />
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Club.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Club.jpg" alt="" />
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Scribble.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"> 
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Scribble.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Gem-Main Bar.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Gem-Main Bar.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> 
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Grace-Milk Bar.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Grace-Milk Bar.jpg" />
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Kanaloa-Club.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Kanaloa-Club.jpg"/>
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Clinic.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"> 
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Clinic.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Fruitbox Bar.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Fruitbox Bar.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!--Large table-->
                  <table class="table" id="Large_table" >
                     <thead>  </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td> 
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Babble City-Crimson.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Babble City-Crimson.jpg" />
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Club.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Club.jpg" alt="" />
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Scribble.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"> 
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Foundation-Scribble.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Gem-Main Bar.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Gem-Main Bar.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> 
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Grace-Milk Bar.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Grace-Milk Bar.jpg" />
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Kanaloa-Club.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Kanaloa-Club.jpg"/>
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Clinic.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"> 
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Clinic.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <a href="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Fruitbox Bar.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                              <img src="/Users/Christopher/Desktop/ClubPedia Landing page/img/Piccadilly Institute-Fruitbox Bar.jpg" /> 
                              </a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the custom CSS:

```
#TextBox {  
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color:grey;
   height:500px;
   width:50%;
}

#Title {
   height:300px;
   background-color:white;
   opacity:0.9;
}

body { 
   background-color:black;
}

img {
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}

table {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just checked the HTML you provided in your example and think there's the problem - it's not valid. There are some lines like

```
<div class="col-lg-3" class="col-md-3">
```

In case you don't know - you have only one class-attribute for an element and can add classes together like

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
```

Guess you should just fix up your HTML, maybe that'll already solve the issue.
Many CSS rules only apply for elements that have different classes at the same time (written as `.classone.classtwo` in the CSS for a `<div class="classone classtwo"/>`). When each class is added as separate class attribute value, they won't add up. Despite being invalid, different browsers tend to handle invalid markup in different ways, e.g. trying to correct it to display as possibly intended. So it looks like Firefox fixes it while IE behaves properly.

Comment: The same code seem to work on other browsers , and I removed the css that dealt with the screen resolution and all 3 tables showed up.

Comment: But you didn't try to fix the html? As mentioned, some browsers tend to correct invalid markup like the double class-attributes you currently have. I would just give it a try. Otherwise it's not possible to find a solution in case issue with IE will then still persist. Just counted the invalid double-class elements - there are only 3 of them, so shouldn't be an issue.